# Gradle take too much to build

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm use Android studio , and when i build  a project , it's give me from Grandle console : Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]' , and it's get stuck on it , and give me no progress !

Answer (score 4):

Well I don't know if you're still looking for a solution..but this might help someone, someday :

1. Go to the `.gradle` folder (C:\Users\your_user_name\.gradle).
2. Create a `gradle.properties` file (if it does not exist).
3. Add these lines in it :

   ```
   org.gradle.daemon=true
   org.gradle.parallel=true
   ```

Comment: org.gradle.parallel=true or #org.gradle.parallel=true

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Buil Tools -> Gradle

Check the 'Offline work' under 'Global Gradle settings'

It will make the gradle build 90% faster.

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything and then found out Gradle wasn't doing anything in Task manager. It was just sitting "IDLE" .... I don't know why they don't have a warning message for that. I guess the software world is just full of bugs and imperfection

I turned off my Antivirus(avast) for an hour and everything started working normal. Build time decreased from 30 minutes to 1 and a half minutes. Lost 2 days but i guess i should be thankful now