# Reduce build time for gradle wrapper

Tags: android, gradle, build

I am trying to reduced the time that gradle takes to build.

I would like to try https://stackoverflow.com/a/27171878/391401 but I am using graddle wrapper. So will those changes take effect?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will. Just put it into your project root directory. See the [Gradle User Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) on how to configure your build environment.

Note that Android Studio uses the [daemon by default](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/ECrb9VQW9XP), so setting it in `gradle.properties` only affects console builds.