# Gradle in android studio takes too long to build

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I build a project in the Android Studio, it takes a long time (6 minutes). I tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758499/gradle-take-too-much-to-build/27171878#27171878) and make server proxy offline but doesn't work. Is there another way to resolve this problem. help please

Comment: Use only those entry in the gradle file..that are useful like for the google map , you shoul not use the all the google play service instead of map service of google play..it will reduce half time for running and compliling

Comment: You should not make it offline. Try to setup proxy if you are behind proxy or firewall.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **.gradle** folder (C:\Users\your_user_name.gradle).

Create a **gradle.properties** file (if it does not exist).

Add these lines in it

```
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Comment: I found the solution, the probleme is in the file build.gradle when i added compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0" but in my case i want just compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0". PS :the package compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0" make your build very slow :)

Comment: How can I do this on mac?

Answer (score 0):

You can use paid android studio plugin called [JRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/)

or Update to [new android studio (Android Studio Canary Build: 2.0 Preview Beta 6)](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest)

But First run will always takes time to load even you use any of above.

You can also try to increase the heap size of memory [Click here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723755/android-studio-how-to-increase-allocated-heap-size)